# PyCharm created a package when uploading to Github, can't see my files now

Tags: github, pycharm

So I tried uploading to GitHub via Pycharm after watching a youtube tutorial on how to do so in order to be safe...

Point is I had some code files in there, everything seems to be in package format now, I can't find my code files, (there seems to be 1 cached file and the rest missing), and in Pycharm I see "library root" now. Is there a way to revert this..
I cant seem to find any of my code files :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so incase anyone else is a Git noob like me (most of what i write I've been keeping private, and only recently beginning to publish things).

What I did was go to version control in PyCharm , you can press Alt + 0.

I went to the Commit tab and unshelved what I had. In any case what i needed was tucked away under version control.